# RequireJS и плагины jQuery

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Я только начал разбираться с RequireJS, но у меня появился уже вопрос. Допустим я имею два плагина для jQuery: a.js и b.js, не зависящих друг от друга.

Вот мой конфиг, точкой входа является файл main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'src/library',
  deps: ['../main'],
  paths: {
      jQuery: 'jquery-3.2.1',
  },
  shim: {

      a: {
         deps: ['jQuery'],
         exports: '$'
      },

      b: {
         deps: ['jQuery'],
         exports: '$'
      }
   }
});
```

Как мне подключить одновременно плагины a и b в main.js через `require` и использовать два плагина через одну переменную `$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно плагины к jquery ничего не экспортируют - они меняют jquery.

Поэтому подключать их надо вот так (формат CommonJS):

```
var $ = require("jQuery");
require("a");
require("b");
```

Или вот так (формат AMD):

```
define(["jQuery", "a", "b"], function($) {

});
```